# How to fetch records from a class which has parent class reference?

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchrequest

I'm new to CoreData structure, I have two classes one is "`Person.h`" and another is "`Education.h`" which has one to many relations ship `Person`<--->> Education`.

Here's the attributes for each classes,

**Person.h**

```
personID (unique) Number
pName String
pAge Number
educations Set
```

here, p stands for person

**Education.h**

```
educationID (unique) Number
eName String
eState Number
eStarted String
eCompleted String
eCenterName String
eBy Person
```

here, e stands for education

Ok, now I want to fetch (all / some) education details for a Person. I've successfully inserted records in both the classes with proper inputs. How to get this done? Any suggestion? Please consider me to correcting, even if this flow would not clear to you (or its wrong).

Thanks,

Hagile

Comment: There should be a property in Person that points to an NSSet of Education objects. Then to access all of the education details, you just use a fetch request for a person and use that property to retrieve the education details. Ex: `somePerson.educationTypes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'd have a Core Data relationship on `Person` that points to the `Education` entity, configured as to-many. Then once you have an instance of `Person`, you just look up the value of that relationship like you'd look up the value of any property. You get back a collection of zero or more related `Education` instances, and you don't need to do an additional fetch.

Your `eBy` relationship on `Education` suggests that you're thinking of this as if you were working with SQL. With Core Data it's normal to have a to-many relationship defined on the entity that has the relationship (and indeed, `eBy` should really have an inverse relationship).

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, you're right, I was forget to add that set in my question, please see updated question. What would be the benefit by having a `inverse relationship`?

Comment: If you already have the `educations` relationship, what are you asking in this question? When you have an instance of `Person`, you get the related `Education` details by using that relationship. What do you need to do that your model does not already do?